# An Android Application that Sends data through USB

Tags: android, serial-port, usb

I would like to build an android application in Eclipse that sends data through a port. As per my thought, start screen will have a textfield and button. Whenever a text is typed and button pressed, the text has go through the port and received at an end. My objective is only to send the text data through the port. To achieve this, please guide me with code. Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "give me teh codes" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to connect the usb via usb manager
this should happen after **permission granted** for that usb

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
UsbDeviceConnection connection = manager.openDevice(device);
```

get Interface and End points

```
UsbEndpoint epIN = null;
 UsbEndpoint epOUT = null;
 UsbInterface usbIf = dev.getInterface(0); // inter will change according to usb 0/1 etc..

 for (int i = 0; i < usbIf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {            
    if (usbIf.getEndpoint(i).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK){                 
         if (usbIf.getEndpoint(i).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN)
              epIN = usbIf.getEndpoint(i);
              else
               epOUT = usbIf.getEndpoint(i);
          } else {
               Log.d("USB","Not Bulk");
              }
         }
```

Transfer text to usb

```
byte[] str = get.getBytes("TEXT");
connection.bulkTransfer(epOUT, str, str.length, 500);
```

hope it helps.

Comment: In my Code, UsbDevice value is showing null;

Comment: and how can read that data on PC (Ubuntu or Windows)?

Comment: `device` what is that?

Answer (score 0):

You will be require to study [Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html) class for this.

Android accessories can be audio docking stations, exercise machines, personal medical testing devices, weather stations, or any other external hardware device that adds to the functionality of Android.